# Saving a json request as an Image in Flask

Tags: python

I have a flask get request like this

```
content = {"vname":"","myPhoto":{"fieldname":"myPhoto","originalname":"flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/jpeg","buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[255,216,255,224,0,...]}
```

My image file is with the key `data`.

```
data = content['myphoto']['buffer']['data']
```

I am unable to save it as a jpeg file.

I am not sure how to decode this object as an image as its currently a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, it could be done like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

content = {"vname":"","myPhoto":{"fieldname":"myPhoto","originalname":"flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/jpeg","buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[255,216,255,224,0,20]}}}
data = content['myPhoto']['buffer']['data']
str_data = ''.join(chr(d) for d in data) # build string using list comprehension
bytes_data = str_data.encode() # build bytes array from string
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as f: # open file for writing bytes
    f.write(bytes_data) # write bytes array to file
```

Code of course is not perfect and could be used as starting point.

Comment: @AntonvBR Thanks I've edited my answer and improved file operation